# Why does ExecutorService.FixedThreadPool(n) cause excessive memory use?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-leaks, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have a GUI class which at the click of a button creates and executes a SwingWorker subclass. The SwingWorker class holds a reference to the main one to tell it to update a progress bar. The SwingWorker class instantiates the ExecutorService.FixedThreadPool and submits a number m Callable subclass that returns an ArrayList. When run, the Mac Activity Monitor records n * initial memory where n is the number of threads performed so far, and the process takes a large % of the cpu. The effect of running on 1 thread vs 4 or even 8 with m > n is also a measly 10% gain in speed if any. When creating a new Callable (subclass named DetectFruitTask) with a number of parameters passed in, am I creating a strong reference to it that makes the GC keep it in play?

Here is the one line that might be of concern (note I am not keeping a reference to the returned Callable object and it still causes the memory overload):

```
executor.submit(new FruitDetectTask((int[])stack.getProcessor(i).getPixels(), sobel, width, height, lumaWeight, sdWeight, threshold));
```

And here is the actual Callable:

```
public class FruitDetectTask implements Callable<ArrayList<FruitObject>> {

private int[] pixels;
private float[][] sobel;
private float lumaWeight;
private float sdWeight;
private int width;
private int height;
private float threshold;

public FruitDetectTask(int[] pixels, float[][] sobel, int width, int height, float lumaWeight, float sdWeight, float threshold) {
    this.pixels = pixels;
    this.sobel = sobel;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.lumaWeight = lumaWeight;
    this.sdWeight = sdWeight;
    this.threshold = threshold;
}

@Override
public ArrayList<FruitObject> call() throws Exception {

    float[] edgeIntensities = EdgeDetector.calculateEdgeIntensities(pixels, sobel, width, height, lumaWeight, sdWeight);
    byte[] edges = new byte[edgeIntensities.length];

    for (int j = 0; j < edgeIntensities.length; j++) {
        if (edgeIntensities[j] > threshold) {
            edges[j] = (byte)0;
        } else {
            edges[j] = (byte)255;
        }
    }

    ArrayList<FruitObject> fruits = FruitDetector.detect(edges, width, height);

    return fruits;
}
}
```

Comment: It should not be a surprise that a fixed thread pool with `n` threads creates `n` threads.

Comment: If I have an app using 1 GB of memory and I initialize n threads that hold references to objects only using 5 MB each, shouldn't the total memory be 1 GB + 5 MB * n? My question isn't why are there n threads its why is there 1 GB * n memory used in the explained scenario.